# SharePoint 2010: Copy the data on 'Name' column to 'Title' column for existing documents

Tags: 2010, document-library, calculated-column, copy-item

I have a document library and I need to  copy the data on 'Name' column to 'Title' column. Be noted that the existing documents have already an existing data on the 'Title' column and I needed to update it so that it will be similar to 'Name' column.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a powershell script to update the Title Column with the values from the Name Column by looping through all items

Comment: Ca you please give me a sample code on how to do that in powershell? I haven't used it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a worfklow in Sharepoint Designer, which triggered if the item modifies. Make an extra Yes/No field, and a datasheet field, which has only a few columns (including the new Y/N, of course :-) ) and has many rows. You can easily modify a plenty of items with this Y/N field. My experience: 100 items/pages works enough fast, and even 5000 item can modify within an hour (depends on the server performance and your bandwidth),